# Better way to get int from FragmentActivity in a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, int, android-fragmentactivity

Hi im trying to get an int from my FragmentActivity and i have a way to do this but the code get very cluttered and long and i did this to shorten the problem and i don't get any errors while in the editor but when i run the app it eminently crashes. Any suggestions?

An example of the code that **doesn't** work

```
MainActivity mainActivity = ((MainActivity)getActivity());

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.upgrades_fragment, container, false);

    TextView AirFreshenersCost = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.AirFreshenersCost );

    if(mainActivity.amountAirFresheners == 5){
        AirFreshenersCost.setText("5");
    }

    return view;
}
```

LogCat

```
10-27 22:16:37.333: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-27 22:16:37.333: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-27 22:16:37.333: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): at com.free.dennisg.clickingbad.fragments.UpgradesFragment.onCreateView(UpgradesFragment.java:40)
10-27 22:16:37.333: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
10-27 22:16:37.333: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
10-27 22:16:37.333: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
10-27 22:16:37.333: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
10-27 22:16:37.333: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
10-27 22:16:37.333: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
10-27 22:16:37.333: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
10-27 22:16:37.333: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
10-27 22:16:37.333: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
10-27 22:16:37.333: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:244)
10-27 22:16:37.333: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
10-27 22:16:37.333: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
10-27 22:16:37.333: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:531)
10-27 22:16:37.333: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
10-27 22:16:37.333: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-27 22:16:37.333: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-27 22:16:37.333: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-27 22:16:37.333: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
10-27 22:16:37.333: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 22:16:37.333: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-27 22:16:37.333: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
10-27 22:16:37.333: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
10-27 22:16:37.333: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

An example of the code **that** work

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.upgrades_fragment, container, false);

    TextView AirFreshenersCost = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.AirFreshenersCost );

    if(((MainActivity)getActivity()).amountAirFresheners == 5){
        AirFreshenersCost.setText("5");
    }

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the int as a static variable on the MainActivity. Then, you could reference that instead of referencing a public instance variable.

`if (MainActivity.AIR_FRESHENER_COUNT == 5) { ...`

I think the reason for the crash is that you are holding a reference to the activity, and the activity can get created and destroyed even while your fragment lives on, so that reference might be null (it's hard to tell what exactly the NPE is on without knowing the line numbers from your original file).

Comment: Thanks, it's easier than `((MainActivity)getActivity()` :D

Comment: The answer of @atroutt is not a good idea really. It makes class design broken down.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define an interface to encapsulate your activity and fragment. As the concept of oop the activities should not know the details of her fragments and also the fragments should not know her mother activities.
Dummy:

```
Interface IGetNumber { int getNum();}

class MyActivity : IGetNumber

class MyFragment {
          IGetNumber mNumGetter;

         onAttach(activity){
                If activity is an IGetNumber {
                           mNumGetter = (IGetNumber)activity;
                 }
        }

        any method(){
                If mNumGetter is valid {
                         Call mNumGetter.getNum();
                 }


}
```